# Can an OAuth token from Azure AD graph be used to request an OAuth token for Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, graph, oauth

We have a legacy application that uses AAD Graph (graph.windows.net). We are now looking to add features that require use of the new Microsoft Graph API (graph.microsoft.com). OAuth token when a user logs in presently is only valid for the AAD graph.

In order to avoid moving all of our legacy code simultaneously to the MS Graph API, is there a way to request a new OAuth token for MS Graph on behalf of the logged in user's AAD Graph OAuth token? Would like to minimize code changes on our system, but also don;t want to prompt the user to log in twice.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request a token based on an access token for AAD Graph API. *However*, if the refresh token you got along with the access token is a so called multi-resource refresh token, you can use *that* to request an access token for MS Graph, on behalf of the user of course. Vittorio Bertocci's blog is quite a good reference for this: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/

Another choice would be to acquire an access token for MS Graph at the same time as you acquire the AAD Graph API access token using e.g. the authorization code.